# Do Execution Context created first or main function called first while executing a JS file?

Tags: javascript, executioncontext

While executing a js file, firstly a global execution context is created to execute the entire js code. Again, a main function is also get called to execute the same code.

So my question is, do the main function is called first and then the global execution context gets created or first the global execution context gets created first and then the main function gets created?

I think, first the Global Execution context gets created and then the main function gets created.

Comment: *"Again, a main function is also get called to execute the same code."* What makes you say that? There is no "main" function concept in JavaScript like there is in C or Java.

Answer (score 0):

> Again, a main function is also get called to execute the same code.

JavaScript doesn't have any "main" function concept like there is in some C or Java contexts. Once the global execution context is created, execution starts at the beginning of the code in the script you ran (more in [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules.html#sec-runtime-semantics-scriptevaluation)). (Assuming we're talking about a non-module script.) For example:

```js
console.log("No main function");
```

Answer (score 0):

In js there is nothing like main function

So the first time Js engine ( v8 engine ) recieves a code what it does ->
-- it creates GEC (GLOBAL EXECUTION CONTEXT).
-- Then it start the execution of code
line by line ** here i am taking
about synchronous code **
-- When it encounters Asynchronous
code it throws it into Callback
Queue
-- After every code executed , the GEC
is removed by Js engine

Answer (score 0):

usually script  languages(python,JS,...) don't need to main function. they bootstrapping process by file and not function . also if you need async process you should define another function . name of this function does not matter . JS developers prefer `main` as function name

```
async function main(){ // main or whatever
   const m=await loadFile();
}

main().then(console.log,console.error);
```